# method '~' of object '~' failed on publish in Visual Basic 6

Tags: vb6

I am trying to export a COM DLL with Crystal Reports from a very old project. I changed version 8 to version 10 due a serious issue when exporting and we did not have that old version anymore. I checked the references to point to version 10.

When I run it everything works fine but when I go to tools -> Publish ->Build outputs... I get the error: "method '~' of object '~' failed". I have checked the references and even add MDAC 2.7 that was previously missing. Does anyone knows what I am missing here? I ran it with a full compile with no problems.

Comment: There is no Publish or Build Outputs in VB6.  Is this question mistaggged?

Comment: It is. As I stated in the question Go to tools menu then Publish and then Build outputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is go to File -> Make (Dll Name)... I could go to File -> Make Project Group but I only needed the CrystalReport COM. I published in the server that had Crystal Reports 10 and it is working. So far So god.